# what is the best way to detect a successful facebook like from a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, windows-phone

I'm very new to facebook development. I'm trying to link a user to liking my facebook page and then detecting the successful like. I've seen a lot of web code for this, but what would be the best approach to do this from a mobile app? Hopefully something I can easily port between all mobile app platforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the Javascript SDK lets you subscribe to a Like event directly in the app.

There's two methods you could use:

1. Use the Realtime Updates API to subscribe to the user.likes object, which will fire a callback at your server when the 'likes' changes.

   You can then check this periodically in your app.

   The obvious con is that you need to have a server backend component to your app.
2. Continually request the user.likes object through the Graph API in your app.

   This isn't particularly great either because you have to keep making requests to Facebooks servers, which usually take up to 2 seconds to reply.

You might easily end up hitting the daily request limit if you have a lot of users all continually making requests.

--

Now - you say you're writing mobile apps for all platforms; if by chance you're doing this as mobile web (i.e. Phonegap or similar) then you're in luck, you can do this through a Phonegap plugin.

Comment: I have a PHP mysql server backend, so option 1 sounds appealing thanks! Do I still need to worry about the quotas?

Comment: #2 should work too if I do the check just after the user taps the like button in my app....

Comment: I forgot to address the question of how to display the Like button - you need to embed it in a UIWebView. You can't use a custom button (as per their policy), and because it's displayed in an iframe, you can't catch the button press event.

It's just occured to me, because its in a UIWebView, you're loading the JS SDK and can use FB.Event.subscribe()

Comment: I see, so since I already have a php based backend, perhaps what I will do is create a common web page that says "Tap the like button etc etc" and this will ask them to login to facebook automatically (right?) and then i can get a callback and record their user id in my db as having liked my fanpage once the callback is fired. Am I on the right path here?

Comment: Sure, that sounds fine. I've just implemented it and put the iframe on a local html page rather than a common external web page, but as long as it's loaded in a webview in your app, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691410/facebook-login-permissions