# Facebook Login Permissions

Tags: facebook

I am following the basic php facebook login example. When I tap the Login to Facebook url, it will prompt the user "MYAPP would like to access your public profile and friend list, and user likes."

I don't need to access the user's friends list or public profile and i'm worried this will scare away the user. I just want the user to be able hit a like button and then get logged in, and have a callback verifying that the like button was pressed.

The sdk says:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#overview:
"During the basic login flow, your app receives access to a person's public profile and friend list"

Any way to do this without asking permission?

Here is my code:

```
$params = array(
  "scope" => "user_likes",
  "redirect_uri" => "https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page"
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

I guess I'm also confused... Do I really need to register as a facebook app to detect when users like my fanbook page? That seems kind of heavyweight...

My goal here:

1. open up a browser that presents the user with a big Like button with some text
2. when they click the like button, ask them to sign in etc
3. once they successfully Like my fanpage, redirect them to a secret url which adds a record to my database that they liked the page

This doesn't have to be super secure or anything... If someone figures out how to "cheat" it is not the end of the world.

Comment: No matter what u do, fb will ask for that permissions while authorizing the user. Theres no way to skip that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 set nothing to "scope", you don't need to know your user's like data in this scenario.
2 I guess you do need to have you own facebook app.
3 You can listen to user like event , and then redirect them wherever you want.

Comment: How do i listen to the user's like event?

Comment: @swinefeaster check this :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ <br> also, you can get realtime-update on server side by https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/.